# How to most permanently block a range of ip addresses using UDP over a mac?

Tags: mac, ip, udp, selfcontrol

This is to prevent certain games from being played by blocking a range of ip's using the UDP protocol. I attempted to use selfcontrolapp but this can be defeated too.

Comment: Any solution we suggest can be defeated if your skilled enough to implement our suggestion.

Comment: I just want it so that it takes more hopes to get through.